# Что значит исключение _Pnext было 0x114999C.?

Tags: c++

Написал программу, которая считывает информацию о студентах (имя фамилию и баллы за три проверочных теста). Работает, в принципе. Но когда выходишь из консоли по завершении работы программы, то вылетает ошибка:

> Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. `_Pnext` было `0x114999C`.

Что это значит? Ниже привожу код программы, в котором место ошибки выделено комментариями.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    fstream stud;
    fstream bin_stud;
    stud.open("stud.txt", ios::in);
    bin_stud.open("a.dat", ios::app | ios:: binary);

    int col = 0;  //подсчет количества студентов
    string name1;
    string surname1;
    int test11;
    int test12;
    int test13;
    while (!stud.eof())
    {
        stud >> name1;
        stud >> surname1;
        stud >> test11;
        stud >> test12;
        stud >> test13;
        bin_stud.write((char *)&name1, sizeof(name1));
        bin_stud.write((char *)&surname1, sizeof(surname1));
        bin_stud.write((char *)&test11, sizeof(test11));
        bin_stud.write((char *)&test12, sizeof(test12));
        bin_stud.write((char *)&test13, sizeof(test13));
        col++;
    }

    bin_stud.close();
    stud.close();

    bin_stud.open("a.dat", ios::in | ios:: binary);
    for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)      //вот здесь я хочу вывести содержимое бинарного файла в консоль, все выводится, но после работы программы вылетает ошибка. Если же вывод убрать из кода, то все работает нормально
    {
        bin_stud.read((char *)&name1, sizeof(name1));
        bin_stud.read((char *)&surname1, sizeof(surname1));
        bin_stud.read((char *)&test11, sizeof(test11));
        bin_stud.read((char *)&test12, sizeof(test12));
        bin_stud.read((char *)&test13, sizeof(test13));

        cout << name1 << " ";
        cout << surname1 << " ";
        cout << test11 << " ";
        cout << test12 << " ";
        cout << test13<< " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    bin_stud.close();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнем с того, что это условие цикла при чтении записей из файла

```
while (!stud.eof())
```

некорректное. Например, если будет прочитана последняя запись файла

```
    stud >> name1;
    stud >> surname1;
    stud >> test11;
    stud >> test12;
    stud >> test13;
```

условие конца файла еще не наступит. Поэтому цикл перейдет к выполнению следующей итерации, когда уже в файле записей нет. Поэтому все эти переменные, в которые были занесены значения из файла в предыдущей итерации, будут использоваться повторно для записи их в выходной файл.

Поэтому лучше было бы записать

```
while ( stud >> name1 && stud >> surname1 && 
        stud >> test11 && stud >> test12 && stud >> test13 )
{
    //...
}
```

А еще лучше считывать построчно, а затем эту строку разбивать на отдельные поля, используя стандартную функцию `std::getline` и строковый входной поток `std::istringstream`.

Далее в этих предложениях

```
    bin_stud.write((char *)&name1, sizeof(name1));
    bin_stud.write((char *)&surname1, sizeof(surname1));
```

вы пытаетесь записать сами объекты типа `std::string`, а не те строки, которые они хранят. Поэтому эти предложения не имеют смысла.

Вам следует записывать строки, которые хранятся в этих объектах, а не сами объекты. При этом возникает вопрос о выравниваемости полей, так как строки в общем случае могут иметь разную длину. Один из подходов состоит в том, чтобы перед каждой строкой сохранять ее длину, а затем саму строку.

Например,

```
std::string::size_type n;

n = name1.size();
bin_stud.write((char *)&n, sizeof(n));
bin_stud.write( name1.c_str(), n);

n = surname1.size();
bin_stud.write((char *)&n, sizeof(n));
bin_stud.write( surname1.c_str(), n);
```

А затем, соответственно, считывать строки в соответствии с этим форматом, то есть сначала считывать длину строки, а затем саму строку и заносить ее в объект типа `std::string`.

Вот как может выглядеть запись значения объекта типа std::string в файл, а затем чтение его из файла

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    {
        std::string s("IWProgrammer");

        std::ofstream bin_stud("a.dat", std::ios::binary);
        std::string::size_type n = s.size();

        bin_stud.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&n), sizeof(n));
        bin_stud.write(s.c_str(), n);
    }

    {
        std::string s;

        std::ifstream bin_stud("a.dat", std::ios::binary);

        std::string::size_type n;

        bin_stud.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&n), sizeof(n));

        std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;

        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[n]);

        bin_stud.read(buffer.get(), n);

        s.assign( buffer.get(), buffer.get() + n );

        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
n = 12
IWProgrammer
```

Comment: но тогда почему у меня все работает, и даже записывается в бинарный файл? Да и считывается тоже правильно все, а ошибка вылетает после закрытия консоли?

Comment: и если изменить условие цикла - то считывать будет не все

Comment: @IWProgrammer Ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение. Просто вы записываете и считываете объекты класса std::string в одной программе, пока они еще не были удалены. А если вы разобъете свою программу на две программы, первая из которых будет записывать данные в файл, а вторая считывать, то у вас сразу же вторая программа "вывалится" с ошибкой.

Comment: @IWProgrammer Почему будет считываться не все?

Comment: не, все выводит, извините. Я не совсем понимаю, что не так при выводе. Ведь считывает все правильно, и выводит на консоль тоже правильно. То есть ошибки нигде нет, но когда нажимашь любую клавишу для выхода из консоль , то ошибка появляется

Comment: @IWProgrammer На консоль выводится строка, хранящаяся, например, в объекте с именем namre1, а не сам объект. А в файл вы пытаетесь записать сам объект. Это разные вещи. Строка, хранящаяся в объекте при этом в общем случае не записывается, если ее длина превышает некоторое определенное значение, так как она будет храниться не непосредственно в объекте, а в динамической памяти.

Comment: я исправил режим записи bin_stud.open("a.dat", ios::out | ios:: binary); и все заработало. Не знаете. что ему не нравилось тогда?

Comment: @IWProgrammer Как я уже написал, ваша программа некорректная, независимо от ваших исправлений. Она работает, потому что вы записываете и считываете объекты std::string в одной и той же программе, когда объекты имеют те же самые адреса. Сейчас ваша некорректная программа работает, потому  что вы не добавляете новые записи в файл, а перезаписываете его. В этом случае число объектов и число записей соответствует друг другу. Но это не делает программу корректной.