# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении. Бинарные файлы, структуры

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры

Нужно считать с клавиатуры данные об N фигурах (должен быть метод, считывающий одну фигуру), записать их в бинарный файл и вывести содержимое этого файла. Я описал структуру (вполне возможно неправильно). Организовал ввод, вывод (при комментировании вывода ошибок не происходит). Ошибка доступа при записи возникает после последней фигурной скобки в каком-то xutility (прокомментировал, где именно происходит остановка):

```
inline void _Container_base12::_Orphan_all()
    {   // orphan all iterators
 #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    if (_Myproxy != 0)
        {   // proxy allocated, drain it
        _Lockit _Lock(_LOCK_DEBUG);

        for (_Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
            *_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)
            (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = 0; //ЗДЕСЬ ПРОГРАММА ОСТАНАВЛИВАЕТСЯ И ВЫДАЕТ ОШИБКУ ДОСТУПА К ЗАПИСИ
        _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = 0;
        }
 #endif /* _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2 */
    }
```

Собственно, вот код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

union tfigure
{
    short int rad;
    int stor;
    float dlina;
};

struct sfigure
{
    string name;
    string color;
    tfigure dannie;
};

void Vvod(sfigure &figure)
{
    cout << "Введите фигуру: ";
    cin >> figure.name;
    cout << "Введите цвет: ";
    cin >> figure.color;
    if (figure.name == "круг") { cout << "Введите радиус: "; cin >> figure.dannie.rad; }
    if (figure.name == "квадрат") { cout << "Введите сторону: "; cin >> figure.dannie.stor; }
    if (figure.name == "отрезок") { cout << "Введите длину: "; cin >> figure.dannie.dlina; }
}

void main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int n;
    sfigure figure[20];
    cout << "Введите количество фигур: ";
    cin >> n;

    fstream f;
    f.open("output.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Vvod(figure[i]);
        f.write((char*)&figure[i], sizeof(figure[i]));
    }

    f.close();
    f.open("output.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);

    sfigure curfigure;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        f.read((char*)&curfigure, sizeof(curfigure));
        cout << setw(10) << curfigure.name;
        cout << setw(10) << curfigure.color;
        if (curfigure.name == "круг") cout << setw(10) << curfigure.dannie.rad;
        if (curfigure.name == "квадрат") cout << setw(10) << curfigure.dannie.stor;
        if (curfigure.name == "отрезок") cout << setw(10) << curfigure.dannie.dlina;
        cout << endl;
    }
    f.close();
} //до этого момента нет ошибок выполнения
```

Программа всё правильно выводит на экран, но всегда заканчивается крашем. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот такие вещи

```
struct sfigure
{
    string name;
    string color;
    tfigure dannie;
};
```

которые не являются plain old data, нельзя просто писать на диск и считывать как единое целое. `string` внутри содержит указатель на какие-то данные. Вы запишете на диск только значение указателя, но не сами данные. Пока вы в пределах одного выполнения, указатели еще сохраняются - поэтому у вас выводятся осмысленные вещи (попробовали бы вы открыть файл в другой программе...)

Но после работы у вас удаляются все `figure[20]`, а еще - `curfigure`, в котором те же указатели в `string`, что и в последнем `figure` - а потому некоторая память освобождается дважды (вернее, пытается это сделать, что и ведет к аварийному сбою).

Еще раз - C++ - не C, тут внутри классов может быть наворочено всякое, так что просто так - сбросить из памяти, считать в память - не работает. Кстати, как и в C там, где идет работа с указателями! Считанный при другом запуске программы или в другой программе - да просто после изменения самих структур! - прямой путь к неработающей программе.

Чтобы убедиться - попробуйте между строками

```
f.close();
f.open("output.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
```

"запороть" данные в `figure` - например, забить одним именем - и посмотрите, к чему приведет якобы чтение из файла...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема связана с тем, что вы занесли данные в массив

```
sfigure figure[20];
```

а затем считываете из файла эти данные в переменную

```
sfigure curfigure;
```

В результате у вас оказывается, что эта переменная и элементы массива имеют одни и те же объекты типа `std::string`, объявленные как поля структуры `sfigure`, которые дважды удаляются, что приводит к ошибке.

Вы изначально неправильно сохраняете поля структуры как объекты класса `std::string` вместо того, чтобы сохранять строки, хранящиеся в этих объектах. Поэтому код, который сохраняет объекты структуры в файле некорректен.

Смотрите вопрос [Что значит исключение _Pnext было 0x114999C.?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614589/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-pnext-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-0x114999c) и ответ на него, где описана аналогичная проблема и как ее решать.